# Blank video when converting uncompressed AVI files with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm having a problem converting Uncompressed AVI files with ffmpeg. I can convert a `.mp4` video without issue, but when I attempt to run the same command on an uncompressed `.avi` everything looks fine, but I get an error in Windows Media Player and blank video in QuickTime when I try to play the output file. Here is the command I'm using:

`ffmpeg -i "Uncompressed.avi" -c:v libx264 -t 00:00:20 -crf 22 -preset superfast -an test.mp4`

And here is the full output from that command:

```
ffmpeg version N-54933-g1af9211 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 25 2013 18:05:50 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 40.100 / 52. 40.100
  libavcodec     55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 81.103 /  3. 81.103
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'Uncompressed.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2012-04-16T16:02:12.00409-07:00
  Duration: 00:02:22.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1199367 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 1920x1080, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 96000 Hz, stereo, flt, 6144 kb/s
No pixel format specified, yuv444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] 264 - core 135 r2345 f0c1c53 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=6 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=22.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2012-04-16T16:02:12.00409-07:00
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   32 fps=0.0 q=22.0 size=     820kB time=00:00:00.45 bitrate=14645.3kbits/s    
frame=   62 fps= 62 q=22.0 size=    2474kB time=00:00:01.71 bitrate=11852.2kbits/s    
frame=   92 fps= 61 q=22.0 size=    4136kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=11442.9kbits/s    
frame=  123 fps= 61 q=24.0 size=    5874kB time=00:00:04.25 bitrate=11310.2kbits/s    
frame=  155 fps= 61 q=24.0 size=    7631kB time=00:00:05.58 bitrate=11185.4kbits/s    
frame=  186 fps= 61 q=22.0 size=    9328kB time=00:00:06.88 bitrate=11103.7kbits/s    
frame=  218 fps= 61 q=24.0 size=   11103kB time=00:00:08.21 bitrate=11069.8kbits/s    
frame=  250 fps= 61 q=22.0 size=   12228kB time=00:00:09.55 bitrate=10488.3kbits/s    
frame=  280 fps= 61 q=24.0 size=   13834kB time=00:00:10.80 bitrate=10490.9kbits/s    
frame=  310 fps= 61 q=22.0 size=   15500kB time=00:00:12.05 bitrate=10534.0kbits/s    
frame=  341 fps= 61 q=24.0 size=   17411kB time=00:00:13.34 bitrate=10686.4kbits/s    
frame=  371 fps= 61 q=22.0 size=   18649kB time=00:00:14.59 bitrate=10465.5kbits/s    
frame=  399 fps= 60 q=22.0 size=   19228kB time=00:00:15.76 bitrate=9990.8kbits/s    
frame=  429 fps= 60 q=24.0 size=   20222kB time=00:00:17.01 bitrate=9735.0kbits/s    
frame=  459 fps= 60 q=24.0 size=   21208kB time=00:00:18.26 bitrate=9510.4kbits/s    
frame=  480 fps= 60 q=-1.0 Lsize=   22173kB time=00:00:19.93 bitrate=9110.9kbits/s    

video:22167kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.026926%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] frame I:3     Avg QP:15.88  size:141142
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] frame P:260   Avg QP:18.80  size: 66756
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] frame B:217   Avg QP:21.90  size: 22664
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] consecutive B-frames: 21.7% 51.7%  7.5% 19.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] mb I  I16..4: 17.4% 50.9% 31.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] mb P  I16..4: 12.1% 14.3%  1.5%  P16..4: 58.3%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:13.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] mb B  I16..4:  4.8%  2.3%  0.1%  B16..8: 19.5%  0.0%  0.0%  direct:22.6%  skip:50.6%  L0:28.2% L1:43.6% BI:28.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] 8x8 transform intra:48.0% inter:54.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] coded y,u,v intra: 75.6% 9.0% 8.7% inter: 30.6% 2.1% 1.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 11% 60%  9%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 19% 35%  5%  5%  5%  7%  4%  8%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 26% 14%  7%  6%  6%  7%  5%  8%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] Weighted P-Frames: Y:13.1% UV:1.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000025ea020] kb/s:9070.21
```

My gut feeling is that my AVI file is just too massive. It's a little over 2 minutes long and 19.9 GB. I've tried it on two similar AVI files with the same result. Any ideas on what I should try to resolve this issue?

Comment: The problem is the `bgr24` color space which gets converted to `yuv444p`, something most players cannot display. See my answer to the duplicate, you need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help, and sorry I missed the original question when I did my initial search.

Comment: No worries – it's easy to overlook. I just found out that recent-ish `ffmpeg` actually displays `Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players` in your output. But I've asked the developers if it was possible to raise the error level of this message to a warning (yellow) to make it more prominent.